# Perl DBI / FreeTDS / SQL-Server: How to insert/update BLOB varbinary(max) data?

Tags: sql-server, perl, blob, dbi, varbinary

I am trying to insert binary data into a VARBINARY(max) column on an Microsoft SQL-Server 2014 via DBI and freeTDS in Linux.

Following (simplified) code does not work:

```
$data = "foobar"; # real binary data gives same error
$dbh = <...valid db-handle ...>;
$sth = $dbh->prepare ("UPDATE table SET data=? WHERE id=?");
$sth->bind_param (1,$data,DBI::SQL_VARBINARY);
$sth->bind_param (2,$some_id);
$sth->execute or die ...
```

Results in:

```
ct_result(ct_dynamic(CS_PREPARE)) returned -205 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.28/DBD/Sybase.pm line 138.
DBD::Sybase::db prepare failed: Server message number=257 severity=16 state=3 line=1 server=SERVER text=Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. Server message number=8180 severity=16 state=1 line=1 server=...
Can't call method "bind_param" on an undefined value
```

It seems like the bind_param call tails to encode the binary data correctly. The undefined value error seems to be a result of the failed bind execution. I tried various other column types for bind_param like SQL_LONGVARBINARY, SQL_BLOB ... but the error stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-Sybase/dbd-sybase.pod#String-Data-Handling

> DBD::Sybase supports CHAR/VARCHAR/BINARY/VARBINARY, limited to 255 characters in length up to version 12.0x. As of 12.5 these datatypes can be up to 16K in size - but supporting the larger sizes requires that Open Client 12.5 or later be used.
>
> Sybase does not differentiate between CHAR and VARCHAR or BINARY and
> VARBINARY

It seems that `DBD::Sybase` ignores `DBI::SQL_VARBINARY` hint and sends the data as `varchar`.

Try:

```
UPDATE table SET data=CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), ?, 1) WHERE id=?
```

Also check [syb_use_bin_0x](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-Sybase/dbd-sybase.pod#syb_use_bin_0x) setting.

Comment: This partially solves the problem. `DBD::Sysbase` really seems to sent a `VARCHAR`. Therefore data is now truncated to 1999 bytes: 4000 is maximum for `VARCHAR`, encoded as hex with leading '0x' gives 1999 bytes. I tried to cast it as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, but that does not change anything.